# view state problem

Tags: asp.net

How can i save a list box items in view state?

could some body code please

Comment: You'll have to show us your code first.

Comment: <asp:ListBox ID="ListBox1" runat="server" SelectionMode="Multiple" Width="150px" Height="150px">
                <asp:ListItem Text="first" Value="first"></asp:ListItem>
                <asp:ListItem Text="second" Value="second"></asp:ListItem>
                <asp:ListItem Text="third" Value="third"></asp:ListItem>
                <asp:ListItem Text="forth" Value="forth"></asp:ListItem>
                <asp:ListItem Text="fifth" Value="fifth"></asp:ListItem>
                </asp:ListBox>

Comment: Why would you need to add the items to the viewstate anyway?

Comment: above is the code i want it's items to store in view state.
I mean viewstate["listBox"]=ListBox1;
something like that

Comment: i want it's value to be retain on post back because list box items change for some code and on every post back it return to it's previous state so i want it to persist only the change.
I also want to learn how can i save a list box items in view state
please let me know i am a novice

Answer (score 0):

By default, your ListBox's values and current state are already stored in ViewState.  I assume you have some code which is populating or otherwise manipulating the ListBox's information in your Page_Load() or in a method called by Page_Load().

What's probably happening is that you are re-setting the state on your ListBox on every post.  That's why you see people do this:

```
void Page_Load(...) {
   if (!IsPostBack) {
     list1.Items.Add(...);
     list1.Items.Add(...);
   } else {
      Trace.Write("The ListBox Value is " + list1.SelectedValue);
   }
}
```

Note the call to IsPostBack.  If it's a postback, the value for list1 is already populated in ViewState -- there's no reason to store it again.